# People search query shows invalid refinementfilters

Tags: rest, people-search

I want to get all the peoples whose `PreferredName` contains "Tar".

I have written a search query for this search

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&selectproperties='PreferredName,OriginalPath,WorkEmail,SipAddress,Department,Path,PictureURL,JobTitle,AccountName,BaseOfficeLocation,'&sourceid='b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'&refinementfilters='substringof("Tar", PreferredName)'
```

but it shows an error message "Bad Request" and tells refinementFilter is invalid. what is the error in this query??

Comment: **KQL has no string contains , only a string* matching. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff394606.aspx**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it as below:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&selectproperties='PreferredName,OriginalPath,WorkEmail,SipAddress,Department,Path,PictureURL,JobTitle,AccountName,BaseOfficeLocation,'&sourceid='b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'&refinementfilters='PreferredName:("Tar*")'
```

looks like substring or contains is not supported in refinement filters

Comment: Is it possible to add more than one filter in the refinementfilters? like `refinementfilters='PreferredName:("kumar*") and Department:("dev*")' `or other approach?

Comment: If you can help, answer here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/196733/how-to-add-more-than-one-refinementfilters-in-a-search-query

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter=substringof('Tar', PreferredName)` to find names containing the string "Tar".

Your query will be:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&selectproperties='PreferredName,OriginalPath,WorkEmail,SipAddress,Department,Path,PictureURL,JobTitle,AccountName,BaseOfficeLocation,'&sourceid='b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'&filter='substringof("Tar", PreferredName)'
```

Read More: [Filter Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh169248(v=nav.71).aspx)

Comment: it does not give any filtered answer

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: no, but return all the people set, not filtered set

Answer (score 0):

You can try using "*tar*"

`/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&selectproperties='PreferredName,OriginalPath,WorkEmail,SipAddress,Department,Path,PictureURL,JobTitle,AccountName,BaseOfficeLocation,'&sourceid='b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'&refinementfilters='PreferredName:("*Tar*")'`