# How to add more than one refinementFilters in a search query

Tags: rest, people-search, search-query

My search query is

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&selectproperties='PreferredName,OriginalPath,WorkEmail,SipAddress,Department,Path,PictureURL,JobTitle,AccountName,BaseOfficeLocation,'&sourceid='b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'&refinementfilters='PreferredName:("Tar*")'
```

This works fine. Now I want to add another filter in refinementFilters such as `Department"("Dev*")`.

How can I do this?

I've tried this

```
refinementfilters = 'PreferredName:("kumar*") and Department:("dev*")'
```

But this did not work.

Comment: Refinement filters does not accept string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the way...

this should be

```
refinementfilters = 'and(PreferredName:("kumar*"),Department:("dev*"))'
```

Answer (score 0):

To apply multiple filters via `refinementfilters` property, your query will be:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&selectproperties='PreferredName,OriginalPath,WorkEmail,SipAddress,Department,Path,PictureURL,JobTitle,AccountName,BaseOfficeLocation,'&sourceid='b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'&refinementfilters='PreferredName:and("kumar*", "dev*")'
```

Ref: [Multiple types refinementfilters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808285/multiples-document-s-types-refinementfilters)

Comment: You do not understand the question. kumar will be fintered in PreferredName and dev in Department. not both in preferredName

Comment: ok,.. Congrats that you found the solution